# How to prevent mouse up event on double click in a table in jface

Tags: java, event-handling, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am working on Eclipse RCP. I have a dialog which contains a SWT Table with many rows. When I double click any row in a Table, the dialog is disposed and the selected item is displayed in tree view. All this works fine.

Now, there is a widget on the left (see figure) for navigation to different perspectives in the software. The problem is, when I place my dialog on the top of the widget and double click on the table row, 2 events are fired.

1. Double click of table from my dialog.
2. Single click on the widget item.

[image]

In the figure, the red box represents the widget underneath the dialog. If I double click on table item within this red box, the widget also takes up the event. If I click anywhere outside this red box, everything works fine.
Widget items open new perspective. So, **the problem is, it looks like double clicking on Table is causing a perspective switch.** I want to correct this.
I do not have access to the code for this widget. I have full access to the table.
My question is, how can I prevent this from happening?

At the moment, after trying different workarounds, I observed that as soon as I call dispose on the dialog, perspective switches (as long as i double click within the red box).

Comment: I know you can't change the code of this widget, but do you have access to the widget instance?

Comment: I am awaiting reply from developers through which I can access this widget instance. I must get it soon. If I get an instance, what I must do to prevent this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that it'll work, but when you open your dialog, you can get the mouse up listener from that widget, remove it and add it back when you close your dialog. It's a dirty workaround, but I don't see a better alternative.